# Using Breadth First Search to Find All Possible Paths in an Undirected Graph

Tags: php, graph, breadth-first-search

```
$grph = array(                                                      
    array(1,2),
    array(0,2,3),
    array(0,1,4),
    array(1,5,4),
    array(2,3,5),
    array(3,4));

//The $grph[0] is all the nodes connected to node 0 etc
```

I need a code in PHP to calculate all possible paths from a Source to a Destination in this Graph say Source=0 and Destination=5 using the Breadth First Search

Comment: How many possible paths do you think?

Comment: You mean having a script saying : 
"you have 8 paths : 
0,1,3,5
0,1,3,4,5
0,1,2,4,5
0,1,2,4,3,5
0,2,4,5
0,2,4,3,5
0,2,1,3,5
0,2,1,3,4,5"

right ?